# Combine rows with similar information into 1

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that looks like this example:

```
Order      Bagged        Shipped
----------------------------------
1             Y    
2                           Y
1                           Y
3             Y
```

I want to combine like order numbers into 1 row like below:

```
Order      Bagged        Shipped
----------------------------------
1             Y             Y
2                           Y
3             Y
```

How can I do this in PowerBi desktop?

Comment: Changing your question to exclude technologies you originally asked for after answers are posted is a bit strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data really is as simple as your example (values are either null or 'Y' and no conflicts), I suggest something like:

```
SELECT Order, MAX(Bagged), MAX(Shipped)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Order
```

The `GROUP BY Order` indicates you want one row per order, the `MAX` for the other columns ensures you get the 'Y' (if it exists for that Order) or `null` (if 'Y' doesn't exist for that Order).

Comment: So I made a mistake and the table is a result of a SQL query I wrote and the Bagged and Shipped columns are created in case statements.  Does this mean I need to combine them Somehow in PowerBi?

Comment: No,  you can do things like `MAX(CASE WHEN ... END)` in the `SELECT` clause or even just put your subquery in the `FROM` clause like `SELECT Order, MAX(Bagged), MAX(Shipped) FROM ([your other query]) GROUP BY ORDER`

Answer (score 1):

In BI, select Transform, then add the GroupBy function to your existing code:

```
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Previous Step", {"Order"}, {
        {"Bagged", each if List.Contains([Bagged], "Y") then "Y" else null},
        {"Shipped", each if List.Contains([Shipped], "Y") then "Y" else null}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```